# use removePIE remove the ALSR of app binary

Tags: ios

i have download removePIE from github,and move this tool to iphone:/usr/bin/removePIE.
execute

zhangpengde-iPhone:~ root# removePIE /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/B87766C4-0F0C-45F0-99D0-0AA1410256B5/WeChat.app/WeChat
magic : feedfacf
File is not a MACH_O binary

if WeChat is not MACH_O binary,which file is MACH_O binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removePIE not support arm64,need modify code